# Extracting JPG name from JPG URL Link in R

Tags: r, regex

Quick question. I have url in dataset such as

```
    URL
    https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /10045.JPG
    https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /12325.PNG
```

**I want the output to be like.**

```
URL                                                                        ID
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /10045.JPG  10045
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /12325.PNG  12325
```

Note that I am getting the picture name, in my case ID before jpg or PNG.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential `base` R solution: `split()` each string into a list according to the slash character `/`, then retrieve the final chunk and store it as `ID` -- then, repeat the idea again, but this time split according to the period and keep the *first* chunk.

```
test <- data.frame(
  url = c("https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /10045.JPG",
          "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/personal/abc/Documents/xsdsd asdas /12325.PNG"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

test$ID <- sapply(strsplit(test$url, split = "/", FIXED = TRUE), tail, n = 1)
test$ID <- sapply(strsplit(test$ID, split = ".", FIXED = TRUE), head, n = 1)
```

---

**EDIT**: Removed regexes (since they're not *really* used in this approach) by adding `FIXED = TRUE` to `strsplit()`, which seems to be faster:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  strsplit(test$url, split = "/"),
  strsplit(test$url, split = "/", fixed = TRUE)
)

## Unit: microseconds
##                                           expr  min    lq   mean median    uq   max neval
##                strsplit(test$url, split = "/") 22.2 23.30 32.775  24.20 39.75 172.5   100
##  strsplit(test$url, split = "/", fixed = TRUE) 11.4 11.95 16.975  13.05 20.90  74.8   100
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Thanks, couldn't figure out simple thing as this.

Answer (score 1):

With Python-style regular expressions, this should do

```
r"(.+)/([0-9]+)\.(PNG|JPG)"
```

The name is in the 2nd match group

With PCRE:

```
".+([[:digit:]]+)\.(JPG|PNG)"
```

Comment: can you get this for R?

Comment: @RanaUsman You've already got a good answer, but just to complete: it should be the same as PCRE but replacing \. with \\. 
I don't use R so i don't know if it will work